# How to tell a GridView to open a HyperLink on a CellClick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with several columns. One of my columns is a TemplateField containing a HyperLink.

I want that hyperlink "clicked" if the user clicks anywhere in the respective row. If the user clicks in Column2 of Row1, I want the page to behave as if the user clicked on the link in Column1 of Row1.

How can I realise such feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a javascript onClick event handler to the row.
You can do that in the onItemDataBound event where you can get at the url in your first column

Comment: Ok, I know how to add the onClick EventHandler to a row. But how must the code look like the tell the browser that link should be clicked. Could you provide me with a code sample?

Comment: view.Rows[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:winow.open("h t t p://yoursite", params);

Comment: @citronas Do you only want to redirect to the hyperlink or do you want to select the link as it is in the template column on the client side and click it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could raise a SelectionChanged event. 
In this event you call the selected row of which you can get the value of the first column and execute it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You need to handle *Rowcreated* event.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
              typeof(Page), "gridAction", 
              "function runIt() { alert('Clicked'); }",
              true);

GridView1.RowCreated += (sa, ea) =>
  {
   ea.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "runIt()");
  };
```